# FFMPEG - C API - GIF creation

Tags: c, ffmpeg, gif

I have an image processing pipeline, and I have images in memory that I convert into `AVFrame` and I try to create a GIF with those.

I started from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159920/how-to-use-palettegen-and-paletteuse-filters-with-ffmpeg-in-c) and I just replaced the video decoder part with a conversion of my image in memory to an `AVFrame`.

This work pretty well, but I have issue with the GIF framerate.

Into the `init_filters(...)` method, I don't understand the `time_base` and `pixel_aspect` variables of the argument structure:

```
    snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
         "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
         width, height, in_fmt, time_base.num, time_base.den,
         pixel_aspect.num, pixel_aspect.den);
```

I would like to have a FPS=12, so should I define them as follow ?

```
AVRational time_base = AVRational{1, 12};
AVRational pixel_aspect= AVRational{1, 1};
```

Next, in the loop where I feed the frame to the filter buffer (for the palettegen), I also have an options that I don't understand, what the AVFrame->pts refers to ?

```
    // palettegen need a whole stream, just add frame to buffer.
    ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(buffersrc_ctx, picture_rgb24, AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(nullptr, AV_LOG_ERROR, "error add frame to buffer source %s\n", av_make_error_string(msg_v2, MSG_LEN, ret));
    }

    picture_rgb24->pts += 1; // HERE
```

As far as I understand, its supposed to be the timestamp of the frame, in my case, I have a GIF, should I increase by 1 every time ? or 1000ms / 12 frame = 83.33 ms ? Im not sure, I tried to found the information but no luck so far.

There is also the `init_muxer(...)` method where its possible to set the time_base of the output (GIF):

```
    o_codec_ctx->time_base = AVRational{1, 12};
```

So I get a bit confused with all the place where we have to set the framerate.

Right now, the GIF is well generated (with the palette) in memory using FFMPEG C API, the only problem is that the GIF is way too fast and not at the right framerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found it. You must increment the video pts based on the framerate (12) and the codec time_base (1/100 for GIF).

```
picture_rgb24->pts += av_rescale_q(1, { 1, 12 }, { 1, 100 });
```

**EDIT:**

Even better, instead of hardcoding my discovery, I figure out that I can access it throught the codec, and just have to compute it once anyway.

```
if (ofmt_ctx && ofmt_ctx->nb_streams > 0)
        m_pts_increment = av_rescale_q(1, { 1, m_framerate }, ofmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base);
    else
        m_pts_increment = av_rescale_q(1, { 1, m_framerate }, { 1, 100 });
```

and just need to do (for every frame).

```
picture_rgb24->pts += m_pts_increment;
```